# nodejs crypto library generates object which I need to send over the internet

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I am using the following code to create an AES 256 encrypted messages:

```
// Nodejs encryption with GCM
// Does not work with nodejs v0.10.31
// Part of https://github.com/chris-rock/node-crypto-examples

var crypto = require('crypto'),
  algorithm = 'aes-256-gcm',
  password = '3zTvzr3p67VC61jmV54rIYu1545x4TlY',
  // do not use a global iv for production, 
  // generate a new one for each encryption
  iv = '60iP0h6vJoEa'

function encrypt(text) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, password, iv)
  var encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex')
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
  var tag = cipher.getAuthTag();
  return {
    content: encrypted,
    tag: tag
  };
}

function decrypt(encrypted) {
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, password, iv)
  decipher.setAuthTag(encrypted.tag);
  var dec = decipher.update(encrypted.content, 'hex', 'utf8')
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  return dec;
}

var hw = encrypt("hello world")
  // outputs hello world
console.log(decrypt(hw));
```

The hw variable is of type object. I need to send this over the internet (as part as a JSON response) and the client must be able to read it to. I tried toString() and JSON.stringify() methods on the hw variable to put it into a string and send it over (it does generate a string0, but the problem is I can't decrypt it then as it does not seem to be an right type of object anymore. How can I take the hw variable, include it part of the JSON response and then have the client to be able to run this same code and decrypt it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag is a Buffer, so you need to serialize it somehow. I've chosen Hex, but you can use something else:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
  algorithm = 'aes-256-gcm',
  password = '3zTvzr3p67VC61jmV54rIYu1545x4TlY',
  // do not use a global iv for production, 
  // generate a new one for each encryption
  iv = '60iP0h6vJoEa'

function encrypt(text) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, password, iv)
  var encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex')
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
  var tag = cipher.getAuthTag();
  return {
    content: encrypted,
    tag: tag.toString('hex')
  };
}

function decrypt(encrypted) {
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, password, iv)
  decipher.setAuthTag(new Buffer(encrypted.tag, 'hex'));
  var dec = decipher.update(encrypted.content, 'hex', 'utf8')
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  return dec;
}

var hw = JSON.stringify(encrypt("hello world"));
console.log(hw);
console.log(decrypt(JSON.parse(hw)));
```

Comment: Btw, Buffer is by default serialized to hex, so the first `.toString('hex')` is not necessary.