# How to encrypt text with crypto without increasing too much size?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I am encrypting text like this (node.js):

```
var text = "holds a long string..."
var cipher = crypto.createCipher("aes128", "somepassword")
var crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex')
crypted += cipher.final('hex');
```

If I save `text` to a file directly, it is N bytes. If I save `crypted`, the file size is about N * 2 bytes.

Any way to make the crypted text is N bytes as close as possible?

Comment: Good crypto works in terms of bytes, not strings. Although the *input* bytes may be drawn from e.g. UTF 8 encoding, the output will definitely not be. So, you need a way to go from *arbitrary* bytes back into a string, and most such encodings (such as Base-64) will result in expanding the size compared to the original input. So, either accept the increase, or use rubbish crypto.

Comment: Never use `createCipher` it *derives* the key from the password in a very weak way (MD5). It is deprecated now. Use `createCipheriv` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A modern cipher like AES works on binary data. When you encrypt character data, it is first transformed into a binary representation. This is basically what UTF-8 encoding does. After encryption, you get arbitrary binary data out, which is not necessarily a valid UTF-8 encoding (almost all encodings have a special structure) when you try to decode it.

If you omit the `output_encoding` from `Cipher#update` and `Cipher#final`, you get a `Buffer`, which you can concatenate or write to a file. It manages the data in a binary format, but defaults to Hex when printed. When you write the Buffers to a file, the file size will be close to the plaintext size, but it will never reach it.

AES is a block cipher and can only encrypt a single block of exactly 16 bytes. A mode of operation like ECB or CBC enables you to encrypt *multiple* blocks. Finally, a padding scheme like the default PKCS#7 padding enables you to encrypt texts of arbitrary length. This padding always adds some bytes before the actual decryption. To be precise, it adds from 1 to 16 bytes.

You can use `cipher.setAutoPadding(false)` to prevent padding, but then you will need to pad yourself. You could also use a streaming mode like CTR ("aes-128-ctr"), but then you *need* to provide a *unique* IV (nonce) of 12 bytes for it have any security. This nonce doesn't have to be secret, but you have to transport it to the decrypter.

In the end it is really not possible for the ciphertext to be exactly the same size as the plaintext. There is always something that inflates the ciphertext.

---

Never use the `crypto.createCipher`. You need to use a *randomized* cipher to get semantic security. Use `crypto.createCipheriv` with a fresh and random IV. For CTR mode, the IV must be unique and for CBC mode, it must be unpredictable.

Always use authenticated encryption. It enables you to detect wrong keys and (malicious) tampering of ciphertexts. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34864917/1816580) an example with AES-GCM.

Comment: I agree, one shoud never use ECB! This can't be stressed enough. However, the cipher id `aes128` is an alias for `aes-128-cbc` already, so at least it's not the worst default.

Comment: @Scolytus Thanks! I always assumed that it behaves in the same way as in Java.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your `'hex'` encoding. Basically you advise the cipher to

1. get a binary representation of your string `text` using the `utf8` encoding
2. encrypt it
3. transform the binary encoded bytes to a string using `hex` encoding

Hexadecimal encoding uses 2 bytes to represent 1 actual byte, thus you get a file size approximately twice the size of your plain text.

The solution is to use a more efficient coding for your ciphertext which is still able to hold all possible byte values, which rules out a simple string. Try:

```
var crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');
crypted += cipher.final('base64');
```

This will encode the ciphertext as a [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded string.

I have created an [online example](https://repl.it/Bf8q/3), the results are:

```
text:                  488890
crypted hex length:    977792, ratio: 2.0000245453987606
crypted base64 length: 651864, ratio: 1.3333551514655648
```

**Security Announcement**: Don't use this key/IV generation in production. I would highly advise to use a different IV for each encryption, using `crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)`. But for a demo purpose this is fine.

Comment: The size becomes smaller but still close to N * 2 bytes. For example, without encryption, size = 97681. With earlier hex version, size = 19532. With your version, size = 180936.

Comment: That's strange, and I can't reprodcuce that. See the example in the updated answer.

Comment: @JoeHuang If padding is used the input data will have padding bytes added but no more than the size of one block, 16-bytes for AES. The input data will be encrypted and the encrypted size will be exact the same length. Otherwise you are doing something wrong and the best bet is hex encoding which doubles the data length. In the case of the comment the int size is 97681-bytes, padding would increase that to 97668-bytes, the encrypted size would also be 97668-bytes. Do some hex dumps and examine the data.